# Missing conclusion in proof convergence radius

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, proof-verification, convergence-divergence, power-series

> If the limit of $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left\vert\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}\right\vert$ with $c_n\neq 0$ exisits, then $R:=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left\vert\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}\right\vert$ is the convergence radius of power series $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n(z-z_0)^n$

I know that these proof is really common but I only found proofs by using some formulars and consequences of the ratio test. So, these things I've noted:

---

Let $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left\vert\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}\right\vert$ exist and let $f(z)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n(z-z_0)^n$ a given power series. Then one can say that
$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \left\vert\frac{c_n(z-z_0)^n}{c_{n+1}(z-z_0)^{n+1}}\right\vert=\frac{1}{\vert z-z_0\vert}\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left\vert\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}\right\vert=(*)$$

---

The first fraction is a fact of the ratio test, isn't it? Unfortunately I don't know another starting because we didn't introduce the ratio test in the lecture yet.

Furthermore I'm not sure how to go on after the (*). I know that the series converges if $r<\vert z-z_0\vert$ and that $R=\sup\{r\geq 0:\exists z_0\in\mathbb{C}$ with $r=\vert z-z_0\vert\}$.

---

Any hints? Thank you so much!

Comment: **What is the question**, anyway??

Comment: Oh sorry, it's not clearly enough. I don't know how to go on after (*). And where the first fraction comes from. I saw this in many proofs.

Comment: @ja "To go"... **where** ? If the limit of $\;\left|\frac{c_n}{c_{n+1}}\right|\;$ is $\;R\;$ , then after (*) you have $\;\frac{R}{|z-z_0|}\;$ ... what else?

Comment: Yeah, I know, but why I can assume that the limit is $L$?

Comment: @j Because **you** say that limit exists!! **You** wrote "Let the limit exist..." ... and I still don't know was ist die Frage...

Comment: Is this proof correct or not? If not, where is the mistake? Sorry for complicating that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ratio test for the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n$ tells you that

> if the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$ exists and is less than $1$, then the series converges.

Let's apply this to the power series
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n(z-z_0)^n
$$
You want to compute the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|c_{n+1}(z-z_0)^{n+1}|}{|c_n(z-z_0)^n|}=
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|c_{n+1}|}{|c_n|}|z-z_0|
$$
Since we're assuming the limit
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|c_{n}|}{|c_{n+1}|}=l
$$
exists, we have three cases.

#### Case 1: $l=\infty$

In this case we can conclude that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|c_{n+1}|}{|c_n|}|z-z_0|=0<1
$$
so the series converges for every $z$.

#### Case 2: $l$ is finite and $l>0$

In this case we can conclude that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|c_{n+1}|}{|c_n|}|z-z_0|=\frac{|z-z_0|}{l}
$$
This is less than $1$ if and only if $|z-z_0|<l$.

#### Case 2: $l=0$

In this case we can conclude that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{|c_{n+1}|}{|c_n|}|z-z_0|=
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $z=z_0$} \\[4px]
\infty & \text{if $z\ne z_0$}
\end{cases}
$$
Thus the series converges only if $z=z_0$.

Another known consequence of the ratio test is that

> if the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{|a_{n+1}|}{|a_n|}$ exists and is greater than $1$, then the series does not converge.

This is only relevant for case 2, where we can say that the power series

- converges if $|z-z_0|<l$;
- does not converge if $|z-z_0|>l$.